# Problems resizing a Mac partition with gparted

Tags: partitioning, gparted, mac

I have a MacBook pro late 2011, with both a OS X partition and an Ubuntu partition that worked perfectly fine.

Until for some reason I decided to shrink the OS X partition (hfs+) with GParted from Ubuntu. It took twelve hours, GParted said everything was fine. I checked the filesystem for errors, which were found, but again they were fixed correctly, and GParted was able to see the shrinked partition.

However, when I tried to boot into Mac it seemed to work, but before the progress bar under the apple finished progressing, it switched into a white cross circled sign, forever.

I booted in recovery mode, but disk utility could not see the shrinked mac partition (although gparted could), so I could not run the SOS or even reinstall the system on that partition. What can I do about this?

I don't mind losing the data (on that partition), it would be fine for me to have clean reainstall of OS X (on that partition, since I don0t want to lose my Ubuntu data).

Thank you all :)

---

UPDATE

I used `gptsync` as @CurtisGedak suggest and got the following output:

```
Current GPT partition table:  
 #      Start LBA      End LBA  Type  
 1             40       409639  EFI System (FAT)  
 2         409640    236201983  Unknown  
 3      781170552    782440087  Mac OS X Boot
 4      782440088    976510400  Basic Data

Current MBR partition table:
 # A    Start LBA      End LBA  Type
 1              1       409639  ee  EFI Protective
 2 *       409640    236201983  af  Mac OS X HFS+
 3      781170552    782440087  af  Mac OS X HFS+
 4      782440088    976510400  83  Linux

Status: GPT partition of type 'Unknown' found, will not touch this disk.
```

---

Comment: If I remember correctly, `gparted` and several other linux tools cannot manage the hfs+ file system (unless you have installed a special tool for that purpose). So maybe `gparted` edited the size of the partition (the container) but did not make a correct resizing of the file system in the partition.

Comment: I don't think that it the problem because gparted specs say that the shrinking is supported with hfs+. Also if that was the case maybe it would have refused to do the operation instead of taking 12 hours to complete it.

Comment: It is also possible that the resizing worked correctly, but you moved the head end of the partition, and this means that you must reinstall the bootloader to make it point to the correct address of the partition's head end.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe that is the problem since now I have a big chunk of unallocated space between The Mac main partition, and the Mac recovery partition, as a result of the shrinking. Do you know how can I manage to reinstall the boot loader? Is it a risky procedure? (Also I wanted to point out that the boot manager is able to see the partition with the operating systems, but it won't boot)

Comment: I have no Mac computer and don't know the details, so I hope that someone who knows better will see your question and help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known problem with Mac OS X and it's hybrid partition table.  The solution is to synchronize the MBR and GPT partition tables.  For example:

`sudo gptsync /path-to-disk-device`

See [GParted FAQ - How can I fix missing or lost partitions on Intel-based Mac OS X?](https://gparted.org/faq.php#faq-21)

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the link! Will this command delete any data?

Comment: The command will synchronize the two partition tables.  My recommendation whenever changing partitions is to have a backup in case anything goes wrong, such as a software bug, hardware failure, or power outage.

Comment: `gptsync` gives the following output:  
`Status: GPT partition of type 'Unknown' found, will not touch this disk.`  I will post the complete output on my original question

Comment: From the details it looks like the partition start and end boundaries are now synchronized; however the GPT is missing the partition type.  You might try using a tool like gdisk to set the partition type to HFS+.  You might look at [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/975436/how-to-set-a-partition-type-to-ef02-with-fdisk) for some ideas on how to accomplish the task.

Comment: `gptsync` doesn't appear to be available for Ubuntu 19.10.

Comment: @Francesco what was the resolution?

Comment: @JustinGoldberg Frankly, I don't remember anymore since some time has passed. However the problem was solved, I guess using the input from Curtis